# Remove All Query Strings from URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, query-string, truncate

I would like to rewrite my url's, so that whenever there's a ?, it and everything after is removed.

I have various strings, such as:

```
....html?frame=...

....html?sport=...

....html?type=...
```

So to make it easy, if there's a ? anywhere in the url, it should be truncated.

(By the way, I am already rewriting .php as .html)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please give real life samples: what should the user type in his/her browser, and how it should be internally modified in the server

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669755/trim-query-stings-from-url/8669969#8669969

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?
```

Works, but OP says it reverts the php -> html extension conversion back.

Try it adding the php/html rewrite *before*:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1.html

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=302]
```

I just tried it, and I'm having some issues with `RewriteBase`, which you might need to setup for this to work. Otherwise, looks fine.

Comment: Thanks, Darkhogg. That code had no effect. I did see this code: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]` but it turned the extension back to .php after removing the query string.

Comment: Updated my answer to fix... well, everything. Added some info regarding the php->html extension conversion.

Comment: Thanks, Darkhogg. I'll have to fiddle with it because the position of the php/html rewrite didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

From [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (emphasis mine):

> Modifying the Query String
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. **When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark.** To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA] flag.