# trim query string(s) from url

Tags: regex, string, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

Some urls are generated via our script.  I need to trim all these via htaccess;
I have a few hundred of them, so all ?xxx have to be cleaned.

ie:

```
domain.com/page.html?word=gclid=4nwseuoSg
```

to

```
domain.com/page.html
```

or anything starting with ?, the ? and the rest is not needed.

I tried **RewriteRule ^\?(.*)$ / [R=301,L]** but did not work :(

What do I have to use instead of **\?(.*)**  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the path doesn't contain the querystring. Use RewriteCond to match any none-empty querystring.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^$
RewriteRule \.html$ $0 [R=301,L]
```

I also added a condition that the url has to end in `.html` just in case you want to add some php script in the future.